# ReactJS + Heroku: Why doesn't my website become mobile responsive?

Tags: css, html, reactjs, heroku

I have a ReactJS website recently deployed on Heroku, and believe I have what's needed for a website to be mobile responsive, yet the website just looks exactly how it should look like if it were to be viewed on a desktop. Everything is extremely small when viewed on mobile.

What could be the issue?

Here is the HTML:

```
<html lang="en" class="practice">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <title>Practice Web</title>
    <meta name="description" content="practice">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: That looks good to me, minus the formatting. How are you testing it on mobile?

Comment: @arniekoz I just go straight to the URL. What could be the problem...

Comment: Are you using chrome dev tools, device inspector, simulator or...?

Comment: @arniekoz Sorry but are you asking which browser I am using? I was using google Chrome while developing.

Comment: Yeah, how do you actually test that it's not working on mobile? Are you using a device, or a simulator, or something like google chrome dev tools (device inspector)? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/?hl=en

Comment: @arniekoz On actual device. iOS iPhone

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the content extends past the container, like images or something. Try this to see if that's the case:

```
<html lang="en" class="practice">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <title>Practice Web</title>
    <meta name="description" content="practice">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: finally got around to trying it out but unfortunately still doesn't work. Could it be Heroku's problem?